# Call a Specific form view of model in odoo js building Dashboard

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, qweb, odoo-view

I'm Building Dashboard when a particular div class clicked able to call the action against the class, but my issue is wanted to call specific form view for that js function. here is the code.

```
 action_my_profile: function(event) {
  var self = this;
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  this.do_action({
    name: _t("My Profile"),
    type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
    res_model: 'hr.employee',
    res_id: self.employee_data.id,
    view_mode: 'form',
    view_type: 'form',
    views: [[view_id, 'form']],
    context: {'edit': true},
    domain: [],
    target: 'inline'
  },{on_reverse_breadcrumb: function(){ return self.reload();}})
},
```

here is the issue that when a call this function open by default hr.employee(view_employee_form) but i want to open custom form which i created new one for the same model, i'm unable to resolve the issue. please help me out, thanks.

Comment: you can specify which view you need to load in views attribute. pass the form_id which you want to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,you will get the specific view id and return to view it as per your request.**

```
action_my_profile: function(event) {
          var self = this;
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();
          self._rpc({
                    model: 'ir.model.data',
                    method: 'xmlid_to_res_id',
                    kwargs: {xmlid: 'youre_form_id'},
                }).then(function (res_id) {
                      self.do_action({
                            name: _t("My Profile"),
                            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                            res_model: 'hr.employee',
                            res_id: self.employee_data.id,
                            view_mode: 'form',
                            view_type: 'form',
                            views: [[res_id, 'form']],
                            context: {'edit': true},
                            domain: [],
                            target: 'current'
                          },{on_reverse_breadcrumb: function(){ return self.reload();}})

                },
            },
```